# Вызвать emit() без сигнал qt

Tags: qt, signal

В главной форме есть connect, как при открытии второй формы сделать emit() без сигнала в конструкторе? Это возможно? или что использовать для сигнала? Спасибо! если добавить кнопку и там ставить emit(), то работает.

```
void MainWindow::on_action_6_triggered()
{
    results1 = new results();
    results1->setAttribute(Qt::WA_ShowModal, true);
    results1->show();
    connect(results1, SIGNAL(sendData_to_main(QByteArray)), this, SLOT(sendData_to_server(QByteArray)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(sendData_to_form(QJsonDocument)), results1, SLOT(getData_to_main(QJsonDocument)));
}

results::results(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::results)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowTitle("Результаты");
    emit sendData_to_main("{\"type\":\"recSize\",\"resp\":\"show_results\"}");
}
```

Comment: Лично я ничего не понял, переформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы был понятен смысл

Comment: @BeardedBeaver добавил код.

Comment: У вас сигнал испускается в конструкторе, а `connect` в `on_action_6_triggered` написал после конструктора. Уберите испускание сигнала в отдельный метод класса `results` и вызовите его из основного окна после вызова `connect`

Comment: `results1 = new results();` и тут мы получаем утечку памяти :)

Comment: @BeardedBeaver спасибо большое!

Comment: @gil9red а как убрать? я умею только так создавать формы :(

Comment: варианты: 1) хранить указатель и после освобождать память 2) создавать на стеке (это хорошо работает на модальных диалогах) 3) у виджетов есть `parent` -- туда записывать текущий указатель, например: `results1 = new results(this);`, тогда, при удалении текущего виджета, он убьет связанных с ним детей

Comment: @gil9red добавил this в parent, спасибо вам!

Comment: @gil9red стооой тогда получается форма сливается в основную, а я хочу чтобы было отдельное окно. А что если добавить results1->setAttribute(Qt::WA_ShowModal, true);?

Comment: Мне кажется, вы усложняете все. Используйте `QDialog`. Или наследуйтесь от него, а не от QWidget, например. B вместо show вызывайте exec -- тогда диалог будет вызван как модальный

Comment: Наследуйте второе окно не от `QWidget`, а от `QDialog` или `QMainWindow`

Comment: Всем спасибо! выручили